# Show Google PlacesSearch results, based on only 2 WayPoints

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

Hoping you could help me out.  I have google maps appearing on my website, using Angular JS 1.  (A lot of the code is vanilla js though).

On my map, if you search for an origin and destination, the markers drop and show you the google route from the origin, to the destination.  Great! :)

However, I've also written code to make restaurants appear in this result too.  However, due to the google quota, the restaurants stop appearing, after a certain number of WayPoints(routes/legs/steps).

I'd like to only show restaurants results, for up to 3 waypoints in the search result, (due to the quota/API limit).

How do I do this?

Here's my directives code.

```
/* global google */
googleMap.$inject = ['Directions'];

function googleMap(Directions) {
    console.log('map directive loaded');
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="google-map"></div>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            center: '=',
            zoom: '=',
            origin: '=',
            destination: '=',
            travelMode: '='
        },

        link($scope, $element) {
            const map = new google.maps.Map($element[0], {
                zoom: $scope.zoom,
                center: $scope.center
            });

            $scope.$watch('center', () => map.setCenter($scope.center), true);
            $scope.$watchGroup(['origin', 'destination', 'travelMode'],
                displayRoute, displayRestaurants);

            // DISPLAY ROUTE
            function displayRoute() {
                if (!$scope.origin || !$scope.destination || !$scope.travelMode)
                    return false;
                const directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

                const placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

                Directions.route({
                    origin: $scope.origin,
                    destination: $scope.destination,
                    travelMode: $scope.travelMode
                }, (response) => {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    response.routes[0].legs[0].steps.map(step => {
                        placesService.nearbySearch({
                            location: step.start_point,
                            radius: 50,
                            type: ['restaurant']
                        }, (results) => {
                            results.map(place => {
                                return new google.maps.Marker({
                                    map: map,
                                    position: place.geometry.location
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });

                });
            }

            // DISPLAY RESTAURANTS
            function displayRestaurants() {
                console.log('display restaurants function');
            }

        }
    };
}

export default googleMap;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to do the restaurant search on the first, middle and last waypoint (seems to makes sense) then you could do the following.

Replace

```
directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
response.routes[0].legs[0].steps.map(step => {
```

With

```
directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
var steps = response.routes[0].legs[0].steps
// Using first, middle and last step - you would probably 
// want to just use the waypoints as-is if there are fewer than 3
var lookup = steps.length > 2 ? 
        [steps[0], steps[Math.round(steps.length / 2)], steps[steps.length - 1]] : 
        steps
lookup.map(step => {
```

Basically rather than mapping  placesService.nearbySearch on to every step - just map it to the first, middle and last steps in a new array.

Edit

To explain what is happening here.

```
var steps = response.routes[0].legs[0].steps
var lookup = [steps[0], steps[Math.round(steps.length / 2)], steps[steps.length - 1]]
```

`steps` is an array - this means you access its elements via an index parameter.

`steps[0]` is just the first element in the array (the first way point).

`steps[Math.round(steps.length / 2)]` is the middle element in the steps array - we get this by dividing the total number of steps by 2 - then rounding to ensure that we have an integer rather than a float (that is if there are a odd number of steps we won't have a number we can use as an index).

`steps[steps.length - 1]` is the last element in the steps array, we get it by simply taking 1 from the total number of steps (because arrays are zero indexed).

We are using these three values to construct a new array `lookup` and then mapping that to the lookup function rather than the `steps` array.

Here is a generic example with some notes to help.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
var b = [a[0], a[Math.round(a.length / 2)], a[a.length - 1]]

// a.length = 9
// a[0] = 1 
// a[1] = 2
// ... 
// a[5] = 6
// ...
// a[8] = 9
// a.length / 2 = 4.5 - as we can't do a[4.5] we need to round...
// Math.round(a.length / 2) = 5
// a.length - 1 = 8
// so b = [a[0], a[5], a[8]] or...
// [1, 6, 9]
```

Comment: this worked absolutely perfectly!  Amazing! thank you!  I just wanted to understand the maths logic...

So you're rounding the points to the nearest whole value?  And then dividing by 2.  I didn't understand exactly what [steps.length - 1] does.  I think it has something to do with shortening the elements in the array?

Thank you!

Comment: @ReenaVerma - Glad to help, usually to say "thanks" on stackoverflow for a good answer you would "upvote" - or even better "accept the answer" - this lets other users find good answers easily. With regards to the code - please see my edit for a full explanation of what it does in clear terms.

Comment: This is a wonderful explanation and really detailed. I appreciate the effort!  It's really helped me to understand this function and I'll be sure to be more comfortable using it now, in the future more often... thank you :) . I have also accepted the answer.  Figuring out how to 'upvote' though... I'll google this hahahah, thank you Fraser *thumbs up*...!